# how to enable concurrent remote session for Ubuntu server 18.04?

Tags: server, remote-desktop

I am already installed xrdp remote session tool.
But i can take maximum 4 user in remote session.
When i try to take 5'th user in remote session that time existing one user in terminated.
Actually we want to access above 75 user in remote session. how can i configure concurrent  remote session in our server.
Below mentioned `sesman.ini` config file

```
[Globals]
ListenAddress=127.0.0.1
ListenPort=3350
EnableUserWindowManager=true
UserWindowManager=startwm.sh
DefaultWindowManager=startwm.sh

[Security]
AllowRootLogin=true
MaxLoginRetry=4
TerminalServerUsers=tsusers
TerminalServerAdmins=tsadmins
; When AlwaysGroupCheck=false access will be permitted
; if the group TerminalServerUsers is not defined.
AlwaysGroupCheck=false

[Sessions]
;; X11DisplayOffset - x11 display number offset
; Type: integer
; Default: 10
X11DisplayOffset=10

;; MaxSessions - maximum number of connections to an xrdp server
; Type: integer
; Default: 0
MaxSessions=50

;; KillDisconnected - kill disconnected sessions
; Type: boolean
; Default: false
; if 1, true, or yes, kill session after 60 seconds
KillDisconnected=false

;; DisconnectedTimeLimit - when to kill idle sessions
; Type: integer
; Default: 0
; if not zero, the seconds before a disconnected session is killed
; min 60 seconds
DisconnectedTimeLimit=0

;; Policy - session allocation policy
; Type: enum [ "Default" | "UBD" | "UBI" | "UBC" | "UBDI" | "UBDC" ]
; Default: Xrdp:<User,BitPerPixel> and Xvnc:<User,BitPerPixel,DisplaySize>
; "UBD" session per <User,BitPerPixel,DisplaySize>
; "UBI" session per <User,BitPerPixel,IPAddr>
; "UBC" session per <User,BitPerPixel,Connection>
; "UBDI" session per <User,BitPerPixel,DisplaySize,IPAddr>
; "UBDC" session per <User,BitPerPixel,DisplaySize,Connection>
Policy=Default

[Logging]
LogFile=xrdp-sesman.log
LogLevel=DEBUG
EnableSyslog=1
SyslogLevel=DEBUG

;
; Session definitions - startup command-line parameters for each session type
;

[Xorg]
; Specify the path of non-suid Xorg executable. It might differ depending
; on your distribution and version. The typical path is shown as follows:
;
; Fedora 26 or later    :  param=/usr/libexec/Xorg
; Debian 9 or later     :  param=/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg
; Ubuntu 16.04 or later :  param=/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg
; Arch Linux            :  param=/usr/bin/Xorg or param=Xorg
; CentOS 7              :  param=/usr/bin/Xorg or param=Xorg
;
param=/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg
; Leave the rest paramaters as-is unless you understand what will happen.
param=-config
param=xrdp/xorg.conf
param=-noreset
param=-nolisten
param=tcp
param=-logfile
param=.xorgxrdp.%s.log

[Xvnc]
param=Xvnc
param=-bs
param=-nolisten
param=tcp
param=-localhost
param=-dpi
param=96

[Chansrv]
; drive redirection, defaults to xrdp_client if not set
FuseMountName=thinclient_drives

[SessionVariables]
PULSE_SCRIPT=/etc/xrdp/pulse/default.pa
```

Comment: So you are actually trying to create a terminal server with ubuntu ?

Comment: please edit/paste the content of `/etc/xrdp/sesman.ini`

Comment: what you mean edit/paste /etc/xrdp/sesman.ini file ?

Comment: please edit your post and paste the content of the config file

Comment: Thanks for your reply. please find my post again in my config file content

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea here... You might want to check if there are some limits defined in the following file

> **/etc/security/limits.conf**

If you have something like maxlogins value set to less that your connection, that might be your issue....

Adjusting this value to a higher one should allow you to perform more connection....

Again, this is just an idea....

Hope this help 
Till next time
See ya